# zendframework 2 elfinder helper error

Tags: php, zend-framework2, elfinder

I'm using zend framework 2 with elfinder and it's working fine (inside elfinder view).
I have module named options , the problem is when i'm using that elfinder helper inside options view it gave me error called "Unable to connect to backend. Backend not found."
this is the code i'm using inside options view

```
echo $this->QuElFinder('elfinder', array('width' => "50%", 
                                         'height' => "300",
                                    )

                       )
```

;
Please someone help me,
Thanks
Lanka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unable to connect to backend. Backend not found" seems to be a Javascript Exception? Maybe your options aren't complete. Possibibly you forgot to configure 'url' option within your view-helper code.

'url' options seems to configure backend route the ElFinder Javascript tries to connect to. Default route seems to be '/quelfinder/connector' ? ([QuElFinder Module route config](https://github.com/Celtico/QuElFinder/blob/master/config/module.config.php))

```
echo $this->QuElFinder('elfinder', array(
    'width' => "50%",
    'height' => '300',
    'url' => '/quelfinder/connector'
    )
);
```

Comment: It's working in index action of module options, there is a route problem when i added it to add action.

Comment: I found the solution the thing is my url in route is 'url' => '/admin/shop/quelfinder/connector' @Achim thank you very much for your help